# Do enemy abilities level up at the same time as player abilities in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I ask because I want to out level the enemies in some way when playing hardcore expert difficulty to avoid death (I am not an expert, but I play that way for fun), but i have noticed that while playing in groups that the enemies have abilities that they do not have when playing alone.

Someone told me that the enemies level with the player, and that as the player levels the abilities they learn can help to defeat the enemies, but I'm concerned that the enemies might get extra abilities too.

I'm level 9 hardcore.

Comment: You can't outlevel the monsters. If you want the monsters to be easier, so that you are less likely to die, select an easier difficulty. If you want to play the harder difficulty for the challenge, but are worried about dying, then perhaps don't play hardcore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of patch 2.0, Diablo 3 now has 'Dynamic Difficulty'. This means that as your character levels up, the monstars/enemies you fight will also 'level up'/scale to your character's power level. Of course you can always increase the game difficulty, making them even harder to defeat, but even on lower difficulty settings, the monsters will be more powerful for you if you are on a level 70 character than if you were on a level 1 character. They become harder to kill (more health), and also become more powerful (they deal more damage).

Comment: Good answer. Does this mean that besides abilities and loot, there is no benefit to leveling?

Answer (score 1):

As you level up, the enemies level up as well and elites/champions gain extra ability at certain levels, up to 4 total. You can not outlevel enemies, but you can reduce difficulty.
Best way to avoid death is to reduce difficulty until you can comfortably do the next difficulty. I recommend starting playing on hard, because it gives a noticeable exp bonus over normal, yet is quite safe. Perhaps drop to normal for bosses if you're not confident in your abilities and then raise it back up after.